# gnuplot errors: " line 114: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points", " line 114: all points y value undefined!". "Cannot find or open file"

Tags: cmd, gnuplot, mingw, undefined, file-not-found

Here's the image of my data file:
[EPAM_2000_160.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUEdQ.jpg)
When I run it through the cmd prompt, it gives an error: "Cannot find or open file "EPAM_2000_160.txt", No data in plot".
Both these files are present in the same folder in documents. I can't understand why is it unable to find.
Here's the code of the .plt file:

```
#set terminal x11 
#set output
unset clip points
set clip one
unset clip two
set bar 1.000000
set border 31 lt -1 lw 1.000
set xdata time
set ydata time
set zdata time
set x2data time
set y2data time
set cbdata time
set timefmt "%d/%m/%y,%H:%M"
set timefmt "%d/%m/%y,%H:%M"
set timefmt "%d/%m/%y,%H:%M"
set timefmt "%d/%m/%y,%H:%M"
set timefmt "%d/%m/%y,%H:%M"
set timefmt "%d/%m/%y,%H:%M"
set boxwidth
set style fill empty border
set dummy x,y
set format x "% g"
set format y "% g"
set format x2 "% g"
set format y2 "% g"
set format z "% g"
set format cb "% g"
set angles radians
unset grid
set key title ""
set key right top Right noreverse enhanced box linetype -2 linewidth 1.000 samplen 4 spacing 1 width 0 height 0 autotitles
unset label
unset arrow
unset style line
unset style arrow
unset logscale
set offsets 0, 0, 0, 0
set pointsize 1
set encoding default
unset polar
unset parametric
unset decimalsign
set view 60, 30, 1, 1
set samples 100, 100
set isosamples 10, 10
set surface
unset contour
set clabel '%8.3g'
set mapping cartesian
set datafile separator whitespace
unset hidden3d
set cntrparam order 4
set cntrparam linear
set cntrparam levels auto 5
set cntrparam points 5
set size ratio 0 1,1
set origin 0,0
set style data points
set style function lines
set xzeroaxis lt -2 lw 1.000
set yzeroaxis lt -2 lw 1.000
set x2zeroaxis lt -2 lw 1.000
set y2zeroaxis lt -2 lw 1.000
set tics in
set ticslevel 0.5
set tics scale 1 
set mxtics default
set mytics default
set mztics default
set mx2tics default
set my2tics default
set mcbtics default
set xtics border mirror norotate autofreq 
set ytics border mirror norotate autofreq 
set ztics border nomirror norotate autofreq 
set nox2tics
set noy2tics
set cbtics border mirror norotate autofreq 
set title "" offset 0.000000,0.000000 font ""
set timestamp "" bottom norotate offset 0.000000,0.000000  font ""
set rrange [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback  # (currently [0.00000:10.0000] )
set trange [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback  # (currently [-5.00000:5.00000] )
set urange [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback  # (currently [-5.00000:5.00000] )
set vrange [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback  # (currently [-5.00000:5.00000] )
set xlabel "DOY 2000" offset 0.000000,0.000000  font ""
set x2label "" offset 0.000000,0.000000  font ""
set xrange [ 160.3 : 160.44 ] noreverse nowriteback  # (currently [-10.0000:10.0000] )
set x2range [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback  # (currently [-10.0000:10.0000] )
set ylabel "Ion intensity Sector Avg,1/(cm**2-s-sr-MeV) LEMS120" offset 0.000000,0.000000  font ""
set y2label "" offset 0.000000,0.000000  font ""
set yrange [ 1. : * ] noreverse nowriteback  # (currently [-10.0000:10.0000] )
set y2range [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback  # (currently [-10.0000:10.0000] )
set zlabel "" offset 0.000000,0.000000  font ""
set zrange [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback  # (currently [-10.0000:10.0000] )
set cblabel "" offset 0.000000,0.000000  font ""
set cbrange [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback  # (currently [-10.0000:10.0000] )
set zero 1e-08
set lmargin -1
set bmargin -1
set rmargin -1
set tmargin -1
set locale "C"
set pm3d scansautomatic flush begin noftriangles nohidden3d implicit corners2color mean
unset pm3d
set palette positive nops_allcF maxcolors 0 gamma 1.5 color model RGB 
set palette rgbformulae 7, 5, 15
set colorbox default
set colorbox vertical origin 0.9,0.2 size 0.1,0.63 bdefault
set loadpath 
set fontpath 
set fit noerrorvariables
set arrow from 160.36,1. to 160.36,700000 nohead
plot 'EPAM_2000_160.txt' u 1:2 t '0.047-0.068 MeV'    
set term post colour eps enh
set output "EPAM_2000_160.eps"
replot
set output
set term x11
#    EOF
```

Comment: What is the path in your console window? How do you start gnuplot? Where is gnuplot.exe located? Have you tried to give an absolute path, e.g. `plot 'C:\user\xxx\data\whatever\EPAM_2000_160.txt'` ? Mind the single quotes when using `'\'` in the path. I assume you are using Windows.

Comment: Yes I've tried it with an absolute path as well. Also now I tried directly plotting the text file, i.e. line 114, without going through the .plt file....and that is working beautifully.....so it is something wrong with the .plt file

Answer (score 0):

If you open the file with an absolute link, make sure to double each backslash as backslash needs escaping in C/C++ strings.

Otherwise make sure the relative path to the file is correct for the current path from where the application is started.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much! Though I believe something is wrong with the .plt file itself. Because I was able to plot just the text file without going through the .plt file. And I have saved that as a new .plt file. So i'll just add the old commands one by one and figure out what messed up ig.
Here is the code for the new .plt file:

```
# set terminal windows 0 color solid butt enhanced standalone
# set output
unset clip points
set clip one
unset clip two
set errorbars front 1.000000 
set border 31 front lt black linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid
set zdata 
set ydata 
set xdata 
set y2data 
set x2data 
set boxwidth
set style fill  empty border
set style rectangle back fc  bgnd fillstyle   solid 1.00 border lt -1
set style circle radius graph 0.02 
set style ellipse size graph 0.05, 0.03 angle 0 units xy
set dummy x, y
set format x "% h" 
set format y "% h" 
set format x2 "% h" 
set format y2 "% h" 
set format z "% h" 
set format cb "% h" 
set format r "% h" 
set ttics format "% h"
set timefmt "%d/%m/%y,%H:%M"
set angles radians
set tics back
unset grid
unset raxis
set theta counterclockwise right
set style parallel front  lt black linewidth 2.000 dashtype solid
set key title "" center
set key fixed right top vertical Right noreverse enhanced autotitle nobox
set key noinvert samplen 4 spacing 1 width 0 height 0 
set key maxcolumns 0 maxrows 0
set key noopaque
unset label
unset arrow
set style increment default
unset style line
unset style arrow
set style histogram clustered gap 2 title textcolor lt -1
unset object
set style textbox transparent margins  1.0,  1.0 border  lt -1 linewidth  1.0
set offsets 0, 0, 0, 0
set pointsize 1
set pointintervalbox 1
set encoding cp1252
unset polar
unset parametric
unset decimalsign
unset micro
unset minussign
set view 60, 30, 1, 1
set view azimuth 0
set rgbmax 255
set samples 100, 100
set isosamples 10, 10
set surface 
unset contour
set cntrlabel  format '%8.3g' font '' start 5 interval 20
set mapping cartesian
set datafile separator whitespace
unset hidden3d
set cntrparam order 4
set cntrparam linear
set cntrparam levels 5
set cntrparam levels auto
set cntrparam firstlinetype 0 unsorted
set cntrparam points 5
set size ratio 0 1,1
set origin 0,0
set style data points
set style function lines
unset xzeroaxis
unset yzeroaxis
unset zzeroaxis
unset x2zeroaxis
unset y2zeroaxis
set xyplane relative 0.5
set tics scale  1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1
set mxtics default
set mytics default
set mztics default
set mx2tics default
set my2tics default
set mcbtics default
set mrtics default
set nomttics
set xtics border in scale 1,0.5 mirror norotate  autojustify
set xtics  norangelimit autofreq 
set ytics border in scale 1,0.5 mirror norotate  autojustify
set ytics  norangelimit autofreq 
set ztics border in scale 1,0.5 nomirror norotate  autojustify
set ztics  norangelimit autofreq 
unset x2tics
unset y2tics
set cbtics border in scale 1,0.5 mirror norotate  autojustify
set cbtics  norangelimit autofreq 
set rtics axis in scale 1,0.5 nomirror norotate  autojustify
set rtics  norangelimit autofreq 
unset ttics
set title "" 
set title  font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate
set timestamp bottom 
set timestamp "" 
set timestamp  font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate
set trange [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
set urange [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
set vrange [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback
set xlabel "" 
set xlabel  font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate
set x2label "" 
set x2label  font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate
set xrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set x2range [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set ylabel "" 
set ylabel  font "" textcolor lt -1 rotate
set y2label "" 
set y2label  font "" textcolor lt -1 rotate
set yrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set y2range [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set zlabel "" 
set zlabel  font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate
set zrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set cblabel "" 
set cblabel  font "" textcolor lt -1 rotate
set cbrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set rlabel "" 
set rlabel  font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate
set rrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
unset logscale
unset jitter
set zero 1e-08
set lmargin  -1
set bmargin  -1
set rmargin  -1
set tmargin  -1
set locale "English_India.1252"
set pm3d explicit at s
set pm3d scansautomatic
set pm3d interpolate 1,1 flush begin noftriangles noborder corners2color mean
set pm3d nolighting
set palette positive nops_allcF maxcolors 0 gamma 1.5 color model RGB 
set palette rgbformulae 7, 5, 15
set colorbox default
set colorbox vertical origin screen 0.9, 0.2 size screen 0.05, 0.6 front  noinvert bdefault
set style boxplot candles range  1.50 outliers pt 7 separation 1 labels auto unsorted
set loadpath 
set fontpath 
set psdir
set fit brief errorvariables nocovariancevariables errorscaling prescale nowrap v5
GNUTERM = "windows"
## Last datafile plotted: "EPAM_2000_160_CUT.txt"
plot "EPAM_2000_160_CUT.txt" u 1:2 t '0.047-0.068 MeV' , "EPAM_2000_160_CUT.txt" u 1:3 t'0.068-0.115 MeV' , "EPAM_2000_160_CUT.txt" u 1:4 t'0.115-0.195 MeV' , "EPAM_2000_160_CUT.txt" u 1:5 t'0.195-0.321 MeV'
#    EOF
```